# How to retain ionic sidebar on every page?

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I've been fiddling with ionic,  but I've ran into an issue. If I make a new project with a sidebar,  upon navigation to a child state sidebar button disappears and is replaced with a back button. How can I retain sidebar button on every state./page?

Comment: You can add the sidebar in your index.html. you may check this [link](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/JdtuG) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every state/page you should add the following `<ion-nav-buttons>`, just inside the `<ion-view>` and before the `<ion-content>`:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

So, a full simple example would look something like this:

```
<ion-view view-title="Some title">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content>
        Some content
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This would add the "hamburger" icon to your navigation, along with the back button.

Comment: Hmm, I was under impression I can have toggle icon on each page at all times. Now I understand why back button replaces it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The More simplest solution===>
check your main html (which has sidebar code) for this - `<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true" view-title="S">`. If ***enable-menu-with-back-views*** attribute is set to ***false***, please make it ***true***.